# Where can I buy BitForce SHA256 Single?

Tags: mining-hardware

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison says that it's $599 and can do 80GHz per second.

Okay, it's not sold anymore at butterfly labs.

http://www.butterflylabs.com/product-details/

Comment: [Looking for this](https://products.butterflylabs.com/homepage/60gh-bitcoin-miner.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the table you linked to says it can do 832 Mhash/s and uses 80 Watts of power.

That model is no longer offered by BFL because it used FPGA technology. That technology has now been superseded by ASIC technology which is many times more efficient.

[This](https://products.butterflylabs.com/30gh-bitcoin-miner.html) is probably the more recent equivalent product, which provides 30 Ghash/s for $649 (ie 36 times the output for a price 8% higher).

Comment: Note: Just a few hrs ago BFL changed its range of products, increasing prices and slightly reducing the claimed hash power. This equates to a roughly 115% increase in price. Their products remain massively cheaper than Avalon's, but they don't have a proven track record yet either, and don't guarantee a shipping date.